# Determine the following set is open or closed in $\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field.
Consider the set $$S=A_1\cup \{( 0,0)\}$$ where $A_1=\{(x,y):x\neq 0,y\in k\}$

How do we determine whether this set is open or closed in $\mathbb{A}^2$?

My Attempt: Note $A_1^c=\{(0,y):y\in k\}$, and $A_1^c=V(x,xy)$. Thus $A_1$ is open as the complement is closed. Then note $\{(0,0)\}$ is closed, so $S$ is a union of two disjoint sets where one is open and another is closed. Thus itself cannot be open nor closed.

Note: I'm not sure if my solution is correct or not. Even I believe a disjoint union of closed and open sets cannot possibly be open nor closed (in Hausdorff spaces at least I believe...) but I recall that $\mathbb{A}^2$ is not Hausdorff, so I'm uncertain whether my intuition is correct.

Comment: In a discrete space (which is Hausdorff)  the union of a closed set and an open set is always open and closed ! So your argument is incomplete.

Comment: But is it correct? If the argument is incomplete, I'm not sure how to proceed from here? Do I show that in $\mathbb{A}^2$ union of closed and open sets is not open nor closed?

Comment: What exactly is $\mathbb A^2$?

Comment: @Math1000 The Zariski topology with field $k$ with dimension 2.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is not correct: $V(x)\cup D(x)$ expresses $\Bbb A^2$ as a disjoint union of an open set and a closed set, but $\Bbb A^2$ is both open and closed in itself. So your claim about sets of this form being neither open nor closed is not true.

Here's a hint towards a correct solution: recall that any copy of $\Bbb A^1\subset \Bbb A^2$ has the subspace topology. So if $S$ is open (resp. closed), then $S\cap \Bbb A^1$ for any copy of $\Bbb A^1\subset \Bbb A^2$ will be an open (resp. closed) subset of $\Bbb A^1$. Do you see what to do from here?

Full solution (that the OP came to in the comments) under the spoiler:

> Consider the two lines $V(y)$ and $V(x-1)$ inside $\Bbb A^2$. Both have the subspace topology, so if $S$ were to be closed or open, the intersection of $S$ with either of these lines would need to be closed or open respectively. But $S\cap V(y)$ is just the origin inside that line, which is not open, and $S\cap V(x-1)$ is the complement of the origin inside that line, which is not closed. So $S$ is neither closed nor open.

Comment: Do you mean that if it is open, then it's complement must intersect "x-axis" (which is a copy of $\mathbb{A}^1$?) with finite many places?

Comment: You don't need to take the complement here. Focus on the hint directly. All lines in $\Bbb A^2$ are copies of $\Bbb A^1$. Can you pick lines which work for you? Your goal should be to find a line where the intersection with $S$ isn't a closed subset of that line, and to find a line where the intersection with $S$ isn't an open subset of that line. (The $x$-axis isn't a good choice because it's contained in $S$ and doesn't do either of these things.)

Comment: y-axis then? The intersection with $S$ should be a single point, hence closed and so cannot be open?

Comment: Good pick - that's half of the solution. You've shown that $S$ can't be open. Can you pick a different line that shows that $S$ can't be closed?

Comment: Will line y=x+1 work? The intersection is a translation of the x-axis with one point missing, which makes it impossible to be closed?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! Now you've shown that $S$ can't be closed, either. so $S$ is neither open nor closed. (I've now added how I would phrase this under a spoiler tag to the original post.)

Comment: @KReiser Should it be $V(x)$ instead of $V(y)$?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is correct or answer your question, but if you think in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($k=\mathbb{R}$)and take the complement of $S$, $\hat{S}=\left\lbrace (0,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\ \mid\ y\neq 0\right\rbrace ,$ we can see that $\hat{S}$ is not open (doesn't contain any neighborhood of any point), neither closed (take the sequence $\left\lbrace(0,\frac{1}{n}))\right\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, which does not converge in $\hat{S}$ ). So $S$ is not open neither closed.

Comment: The OP means a special topology on $\Bbb R^2$, the Zariski topology (see comments). That behaves quite differently from the Euclidean topology...